# AWS Signature Version 4 - DELETE Object on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

Looking for help on building a DELETE request in PHP / cURL to DELETE an object on AWS S3. I've been stuck on this for way to many hours and can't seem to get this to work.

Following these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

The latest error I see is **"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Here is what I have with some adjustments for security purposes:

```
/*
* REFFERNECE TO DOCS
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html
*
* PRIMARY DOC
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html
*/

/*
* access_key secrey_key and the host url are purposely left out or changed
*/

$date_long = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
$date_short = gmdate('Ymd');
$credential = $access_key . '/' . $date_short . '/' . $region . '/s3/aws4_request';
$object_key = '/filename.jpg';

$hashed_payload = strtolower(hash("sha256", "")); // empty hash payload for DELETE request

$request_headers = array(
    'host' => 'examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
    'x-amz-content-sha256' => $hashed_payload,
    'x-amz-date' => $date_long,
);

$signed_headers_string = strtolower(implode(';', array_keys($request_headers)));

/*
* I have tried multiple ways to urlencode this part according to documentation on Create a Cononical Request
* Trying to match the response from AWS Im using only the object key or file pathinfo
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html
**/

// Build canonical request
$canonical_request = "DELETE\n"; // HTTPRequestMethod
$canonical_request .= $new_object_key . "\n"; // CanonicalURI /filename.jpg
$canonical_request .=  "\n"; // CanonicalQueryString  no query params

foreach ($request_headers as $header => $value) {
    $canonical_request .= strtolower($header) . ':' . trim($value) . "\n"; //CanonicalHeaders
}

$canonical_request .= $signed_headers_string . "\n"; // SignedHeaders
$canonical_request .= $hashed_payload; // HashedPayload

// Build string to sign
$string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n";
$string_to_sign .= $date_long . "\n";
$string_to_sign .= $date_short . '/' . $region. "/s3/aws4_request\n";
$string_to_sign .= hash('sha256', $canonical_request);

// create signature
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', $date_short, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $sig_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', $sig_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $sig_key, true);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $sig_key);


$curl_headers = array(
    'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential='.$credential.',SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature='.$signature,
);

foreach($request_headers as $header => $value) {
    $curl_headers[] = $header.': '.$value;
}

$curl = curl_init();

// I have also tried setting the CURLOPT_URL to examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg or directly to the object path
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curl_headers
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
// create signature
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', $date_short, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $sig_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', $sig_key, true);
$sig_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $sig_key, true);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $sig_key);
```

It should be:

```
$signature_date = hash_hmac('sha256', $date_short, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
$signature_region = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $signature_date, true);
$signature_service = hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', $signature_region, true);
$signature_request = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $signature_service, true);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $signature_request);
```